# Python, new unique object for each user input

Tags: python

Beginner programmer here. I created a class that makes a student object, and I need a way for each object the user creates to not overwrite the previous objects and make them all the same. That may be a poor explanation so I will just post the code and the output.

```
class Student:
    """This class holds student records """
    student_id = 000
    def __init__(self,firstname='blank',lastname='blank',age=0,sex='NA',major='undeclared',graduation=0):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
        self.major = major
        self.graduation= graduation
        Student.student_id +=1
        self.student_id = Student.student_id


students=[]
while True:
    new_student=Student(input('Enter student first name: '),input('Enter student last name: '),input('Enter student age: '),input("Enter student sex: "),input("Enter student's major: "),input("Enter student's expected graduation date: "))
    students.append(new_student)
    add_another=input("Would you like to add another student? Enter 'Y' for yes or any other key to quit and print your entries: ")
    if add_another == 'Y':
        continue
    else:
        for i in students:
            print(new_student.firstname)
            print(new_student.student_id)
        break
```

my output looks like this currently:

```
Enter student first name: Thomas
Enter student last name: Hutton
Enter student age: poop
Enter student sex: p
Enter student's major: p
Enter student's expected graduation date: p
Would you like to add another student? Enter 'Y' for yes or any other key to quit and print your entries: Y
Enter student first name: Timmy
Enter student last name: p
Enter student age: p
Enter student sex: p
Enter student's major: p
Enter student's expected graduation date: p
Would you like to add another student? Enter 'Y' for yes or any other key to quit and print your entries: n
Timmy
2
Timmy
2
```

as you can see the only object that now populates the students list is now the same object for both entries, I need them to be the entries that were provided by the user. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The loop is printing `new_student.firstname` over and over.  The loop variable is `i`.  You should be printing `i.firstname`.

Comment: Yep seems like I always make the simplest mistakes, thank you

Comment: How do I write that in code? I need the `i` object in the list, writing `i.firstname` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you're creating is not overrinding the previous, the problem is on your print loop:

```
for i in students:
    print(new_student.firstname)
    print(new_student.student_id)
break
```

It is not priting all students on the list, it is always printing the last added student (which is the `new_student` variable). TO fix that, you could do:

```
for student in students:
    print(student.firstname)
    print(student.student_id)
break
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are looping over students you are not referencing the right variable. `new_student` should should be `i`

```
for i in students:
    print(i.student_id)
    print(i.firstname)
```

But I would recommend changing the i variable to student, so it reads like

```
for student in students:
    print(student.firstname)
```

`i` is typically used to represent an integer index in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the temporary `new_student`.

Just append to the list of students directly, without using a (not so) temporary variable. Same with prompting for another.

```
class Spam:
    """Spiced meat"""
    def __init__(self, firstname=''):
        self.firstname = firstname

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.firstname
  
lunch = []
while True:
    lunch.append(Spam(input('Enter name: ')))
    if input('Another one? ') in ('y', 'Y'):
        continue
    else:
        break

for meat in lunch:
    print(meat)
```

Comment: That's very helpful to know thanks for the input